# Height of my UIScrollView portrait and landscape

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, xcode6

Good morning,

I'm working with UIScrollView for the first time and I'm trying to make the height of the scroll as I have elements in my screen. In my attempt I can scroll through my View, but when I'm in portrait mode I have a lot of scroll and when I'm in landscape mode I have the exact scroll that I would have.

How can I make the scroll showing only my content? Because at the moment I set a height and the scroll is showing too much height in my portrait mode.

I will appreciate any help, because I have search some questions but I can't really go on with my project without that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must have set a height of the scrollview based on the landscape mode.Hence you are getting excess space in potrait.Use autolayouts.Add a spacing constraint between last element and your scrollview the spacing you need.Then everything will work fine in both modes.Also is your content static or dynamic?

Comment: Thanks! I set a height and now it's working fine. I hope it also works with other devices.

Another quick question: Do you know why I can't make the relationship with "Referencing Outlets" inside my Scroll? I have to to something else when I create them in the .m file?

Comment: I didnt get your question.Are you unable to create referencing outlets?ie dragging the element on your xib or storyboard